# What are all the ways to change my attack roll's ability modifier?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, attack-roll

Hexblade Warlock has this line in it:

> When you attack with that weapon, you can use your Charisma modifier, instead of Strength or Dexterity, for the attack and damage rolls.

Battle Smith Artificer has this line in it:

> When you attack with a magic weapon, you can use your Intelligence modifier, instead of Strength or Dexterity modifier, for the attack and damage rolls.

These two are the **only** examples of this I've found. I might be missing something, though.

I tried to google search "dnd change attack roll modifier" but all I got were noob questions like [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72910/how-do-i-figure-the-dice-and-bonuses-for-attack-rolls-and-damage-rolls), [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/2eaiab/5e_q_reattack_and_damage_modifiers/), or basic/universal information like [this](https://dnd5e.info/combat/making-an-attack/). Yes, I understand that *normally* attack rolls are dice + proficiency bonus + STR or DEX. I'm asking about all the ways to change that ability modifier (like the two subclasses I listed above).

I looked at a few Cleric and Paladin subclasses and only found Oath of Devotion's Channel Divinity (lets you use STR/DEX *and* CHA on rolls).

Comment: Yes, I'm asking for a comprehensive list of features.

I listed two (three) ways to do it, but I figure there's probably more ways to do this ... that, or I understand more of why so many people multiclass into hexblade warlock

Comment: If your actual question is "why do people multiclass into hexblade", that may be answerable and it is more directly related to your inquiry.

Comment: @NotArch As neither question has a comprehensive list of answers to this subject (for example, neither mention the All Purpose Tool that lets an artificer cast any cantrip they want with their intelligence modifier), I feel like there might be a case here for finding a way to consolidate the questions(one absolutely encompasses the other) and answers into a single entry, but that's a bit above my know-how.

Comment: @TheFallen0ne I'm not sure what you mean by consolidate - that isn't something we can do, but the duplicate links act in a similar way. If you feel that one of the linked duplicates doesn't answer something comprehensively, the best thing to do is bounty that question and detail what's missing that you'd like to see.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list for all the different ability scores. It overlaps with [this list](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/203974/what-are-the-ways-one-can-avoid-using-str-or-dex-as-an-attack-modifier) for ways to use something other than Dexterity or Strength, but covers those two, too.

#### Strength

- As your ranged attacks (except for those with thrown weapons) usually use Dexterity, it might be desirable to use Strength instead of Dexterity for non-thrown ranged attacks Strength based characters. However, there seem to be [no features enabling this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153530/how-can-i-shoot-a-bow-using-strength-instead-of-dexterity).

#### Dexterity

- **Finesse weapon**. Any weapon with the *finesse* property allows you to use your Dexterity modifier instead of Strength. This works for any class, and is often used with classes like Rogue or Bard.
- **Monk 1** for unarmed strikes or monk weapons, or Kensei Monk 3 from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* for your Kensei weapons allows you to attack with Dexterity instead of Strength.

#### Constitution

- **Damphir Lineage** (*Van Richten's Guide to Ravenloft*): Vampiric Bite feature allows you to add your Constitution modifier instead of Strength with the bite.

#### Intelligence

- **Artificer Battle Smith 3** (*Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*): Battle Ready feature allows you to use your Intelligence modifier instead of Strength or Dexterity, when attacking with a magic weapon.

#### Wisdom

- **Druid 1**: The *shillelagh* cantrip allows you to use your spellcasting ability, Wisdom as a druid, instead of Strength. (Likewise, feats that let you pick up the cantrip, such as Magic Initiate). Duration one minute on club or staff.
- **Way of the Astral Self Monk 3** (*Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*): Arms of the Astral Self feature allows you to attack using Wisdom modifier instead of Strength or Dexterity with your astral arms.

#### Charisma

- **Hexblade Warlock 1** (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*): Hex Warrior feature that allows you to attack with your Charisma modifier instead of Dexterity or Strength. Works only with your pact weapon.
- **Bard 6**: A College of Lore Bard can use Magical Secrets to get the *shillelagh* as a bard spell, and as their spellcasting ability modifier is Charisma, use it with Charisma. (Any bard can do that at level 10, too).

---

P.S. Oath of Devotion says:

> As an action, you can imbue one weapon that you are holding with positive energy, using your Channel Divinity. For 1 minute, you add your Charisma modifier to attack rolls made with that weapon

As you correctly observe, it is not *changing* your ability bonus for those attacks, it is *adding* Charisma to whatever other bonuses those attacks may have. So, if you attacked with a melee weapon using your Strength ability bonus, you now would add both your Strength and Charisma bonuses to those attacks to hit with that weapon.

There may be other ways that allow you to somehow enhance your attacks with other ability bonuses. I only covered *changing* the bonus to another in this answer.

Comment: Good, comprehensive answer - might be helpful to explicitly call out "attack and damage" however. I haven't done the reading but I wouldn't be surprised if there were cases where the ability used for the attack roll changed, but the damage roll was still Strength.

Comment: One method you didn't mention for Charisma is a bard's option to spend a magical secret on *Shillelagh*. It becomes a bard spell for them, so the spellcasting modifier they use with it is Charisma.

Comment: @TheFallen0ne You are right, thank you for the suggestion. Added it.

Comment: Song of Victory only adds Int to damage rolls, not attack rolls, you still use Str or (more likely, with a Finesse weapon) Dex to hit in the first place (and they still grant you their normal damage boost, the Int is supplemental).

Comment: @ShadowRanger You are right, thank you. As the question asks about *changing* the mod, this didn't belong here. I took it out.